# Mod Rewrite URL and always redirect to new url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

htaccess on apache

I have this url:

**mydomain.com/old.html**

I want it to be rewritten as:

**mydomain.com/new.html**

But I also want **mydomain.com/old.html** to always redirect to **mydomain.com/new.html**.

I tried the following:

```
RewriteRule ^/new.html /old.html [R=301,L,PT]
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the leading slash (or make it optional) because it's stripped from URI's when applying rules in an htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^/?new.html /old.html [R=301,L,PT]
```

This would be required to work in conjunction with other rewrite rules, so that everything happens within one module (mod_rewrite), but if you do not need mod_rewrite, you can rely on mod_alias instead (removing the mod_rewrite redirect):

```
Redirect 301 /old.html http://www.yoursite.com/new.html
```

But this will redirect stuff like: `/old.html/blahblah` to `http://www.yoursite.com/new.html/blahblah` If you don't want that, use:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/old.html$ http://www.yoursite.com/new.html
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Redirect 301 /old.html http://www.yoursite.com/new.html
```

Should work.

Comment: But that doesn't work with the rewrite: The page isn't redirecting properly

Comment: What do you get? White page? Redirect loop? 404?